# Algebraic surfaces in the language of scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question

Are there materials(lecture notes, books...) that deal with algebraic surfaces in the language of schemes? I am not good at/familiar with the analytic way, and also prefer the scheme-theoretic language. So, could you recommend me some materials? Thanks a lot.

Comment: To be clear: do you want a reference that avoids any recourse to singular homology, integrals, etc? Most of the popular books on surfaces besides Barth-Hulek-Peters-van de Ven are mostly algebraic but they do use these things because it's easier. It might be worth looking at references that do the classification in all characteristics (after Bombieri-Mumford) where one really has to use algebra for everything. I think Badescu's book does this and there are notes by Bombieri-Husemoller in the 1974 Arcata proceedings edited by Hartshorne. But I seem to recall separate cases for char 0.

Comment: There's a whole chapter in Hartshorne on surfaces.